# Using AFHTTPClient for multiple JSONRequestOperations

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm relatively new to AFNetworking and would like to find a better solution for the following problem.

I am using 2 AFJSONRequestOperations at the start of my iOS application.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation1 = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request1 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    // do something
}failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON, NSError *error){
    // do something
}];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation2 = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request2 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    // do something
}failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON, NSError *error) {
    // do something
}];

[operation1 start];
[operation2 start];
```

I wait for both operations to finish and start further processing.

I thought I can combine both of this operations into the `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests` method.

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] init];

NSArray *requests = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:operation1, operation2, nil];

[client enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:requests progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
    // track operations
}completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    // do something
}];
```

So I would like to track the finished operations and execute the completion block for each operation separatly. Is it something I can perform with AFHTTPClient?

Comment: As it is described in the [http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:progressBlock:completionBlock:](API Documentation): the block is executed as soon the batch is finished

Comment: Thank you for your help! The batch doesn't event start to execute in my case. When I log something in progress/completion block it is not written to the console..